# Efficient/Parallel Apply an operation to each element in an Array in Java <= 1.7?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, parallel-processing, java-7, vectorization

I am interested in ways of applying an operation (independetly) to each element in a Java Array. For example, clipping each element of a numeric array to be no more than a given element.

Example:

```
myArray.clip(5)
```

Or

```
Utils.clip(myArray, 5)
```

woud set each element greater than 5 to be 5

The most straightforward method is to iterate over the elements, but I don't like it for two reasons:

- It is Iterative and doesn't exploit the parrallization chances
- The code doesn't look beautiful, a mapping or vecotorized syntax would be nicer

I need to do such a clipping operation about 5000 times, each time on a 70 X 10 (2D Array)

If Java <= 1.7 doesn't provide ways to do that in the standard library. How can I achieve what I want (two points above) using other libs or Java 1.8 Features.

Comment: For Java 8, you might want to look into `Arrays.parallelSetAll`. For instance : `Arrays.parallelSetAll(arr, i -> arr[i] > 5 ? 5 : arr[i]);`

Comment: .. otherwise you could create your own method. Partition the array into equals chunk size, then apply the operation on each chunk (a chunk being processed by an independent thread). As your requirement is stateless, that should not be that hard to implement.

Comment: 5000 times on the same array, or with 5000 different arrays? (If it is 5000 different arrays, it might (!) be more efficient to throw these operations into an `ExecutorService`, one for each array). Otherwise: Will it always be 2D arrays? Will it always be `int` arrays? All this influences what the appropriate "infrastructure" for this task would look like...

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820424/is-there-anything-in-java-close-to-the-parallel-collections-in-scala

Comment: It will be done iteratively 5000 times, each time clipping a matrix of 70X10 I can not do the 5000 times in parallel because the Matrix in the next iteration depends on the matrix of the current iteration

Comment: @jdv yes similar, but I have a 2 Dimensional structure and would like if I can do parallel operations on it without having to convert it to a 1 dimensional structure.

Answer (score 2):

The traditional Java 7 technique for operating on the data in a collection in parallel is the "fork/join" pattern. The notion is that one decomposes the work to be done into smaller pieces, forks off a task to complete those pieces, and then join each task at the end.

I'm not sure your case warrants this, though. Depending on how complicated a "clip" operation is, it might be more straightforward to create a pair of threads to operate on the two axes simultaneously. Though, I may be misunderstanding your requirements.

Another solution might be a time/space trade-off. It may be more useful to maintain a clipped version of the data as you update the primary collection. Sort of a producer-consumer model, where there is something that looks for changes to the collection, and maintains a clipped version.

Comment: There is an optimizer that with some intelligence and some randomness which manipulates a Matrix, this Matrix is then evaluated and the Evaluation plus the Matrix are then given to the optimizer which then manipulates the Matrix. According to some constrains for the optimization Problem, I can tell the optimizer to manipulate the Matrix so there are no values larger than x. That's where I Need the clipping.

Comment: I come more from a Python Background. I use Numpy and so on.Therefore used to the concise Syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Arrays themselves, but if you have a "Collection" compatible type you can use parallel aggregate operations in Java 8.

Refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html

Comment: One can use the java.util.Arrays.stream(double[] arr) to return a stream that can then be processed using map in a concise syntax. But does the map operation get converted to a parllel operation?

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 features, this is how I went about it, I iterated over the rows and did parallel operations on it. I didn't find any standard methods that takes a

```
double [] []
```

and use it as a stream or a

```
parallelSetAll(double [] [] ...)
```

My code, I use Apache commons-math library for my matrix implementation because it provides utility functions based on the RealMatrix type implemented in the library

Can this code be optimized further without having to go too much too level. Like take things out of the for loop or do the assignments later , etc

```
public static RealMatrix clipLower(RealMatrix m, double lowerBound){
        // TODO see if you really need to modify m or just return a modified copy of m

        //process the matrix row by row, each row gets processed in parallel
        // TODO See if you can directly parallelize on the entire matrix not row by row
        // OPEN implement using Arrays.parallelSetAll Method?
        int nrOfRows = m.getRowDimension();

        for(int i = 0; i < nrOfRows; i++){
            // TODO move the declaration outside the for loop
            double[] currRow = m.getRow(i);
            double[] newRow  = Arrays.stream(currRow)
                                     .parallel()
                                     .map((number) -> (number < lowerBound) ? lowerBound : number)
                                     .toArray();
            m.setRow(i, newRow);
        }

        return m;
    }
```